# CSS - Another % / px issue

Tags: css, pixel, target, stretch

I want my page to be made of two parts : a panel block on the left, and a content block on the right. The page must be stretched to fit the view port, and so must be these two blocks.

Here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Void Museum</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        html * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
        #panel,
        #content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            }
        #panel {
            left: 0;
            width: 250px;
            background: #CFC;
            }
        #content {
            left: 250px;
            right: 0;
            background: #FCC;
            }
        .AccordionMenu {
            width: 250px;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
        .AccordionMenu > header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            }
        .AccordionMenu > section {
            width: 100%;
            }
        .AccordionMenu > section > p {
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #F00;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s;
               -moz-transition: all 1s;
                -ms-transition: all 1s;
                 -o-transition: all 1s;
                    transition: all 1s;
            }
        .AccordionMenu section:target p {
            height: 300px;
            }
        .AccordionMenu header {
            background: #0F0;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="panel">
            <div class="AccordionMenu">
                <section id="block0">
                    <header><a href="#block0">BLOCK 0</a></header>
                    <p>CONTENT 0</p>
                </section>
                <section id="block1">
                    <header><a href="#block1">BLOCK 1</a></header>
                    <p>CONTENT 1</p>
                </section>
                <section id="block2">
                    <header><a href="#block2">BLOCK 2</a></header>
                    <p>CONTENT 2</p>
                </section>
                <section id="block3">
                    <header><a href="#block3">BLOCK 3</a></header>
                    <p>CONTENT 3</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I want the accordion to fit the page height, but the headers have a fixed size in pixels. I would need to do something like :

```
.AccordionMenu section:target p {
    height: 100% - 40px;
    }
```

Any tips about how i could do this without using ugly hacks please? Is there also a way to use anchors and :target without having to use IDs?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Avoid the universal selector: http://www.kobashicomputing.com/avoid-using-universal-css-selector

Comment: what about implementing it in javascript?

Comment: Amberlamps :
Thanks but i'm just testing if i can create what i want to create. This is not a final version so i try to keep it as simple as possible until i know how to do, then i'll care about the details.

Sven Bieder: 
I would like to make this with pure CSS. JavaScript resizing is really ugly (already used that for something else). If the js takes time to load, you can see the block being resized on first page load, and it doesn't look clear. Also it's a shame if such a simple thing can't be done using css considering all the sophisticated tools CSS 3 provide...

Answer (score 0):

```
.AccordionMenu { 
position:relative;
}
.AccordionMenu section:target p {
position: absolute;
top:40px;
bottom:0;
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not able to make this work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For your height, use [the calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
height: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Make sure to keep the spaces around the minus sign or it won't work.